# What should DevOps engeneer/SRE know about networking?

Tags: networking

What should DevOps engeneer/SRE know about networking?

Which tools\protocols\technologies? Beside different cloud-specific knowledge about network constructions and limitations.

Comment: Not sure if the question quite fit on this site, but as a network guy which have to deal with dev ops / developers on a daily basis, I like it ;)